# Trying to run nodejs script with npm run build

Tags: node.js, npm

I was trying to run this script: https://github.com/drenther/bdnd_example, but then I got this error: npm ERR! Invalid name: "Line up the heroes"

I've tried reinstalling everything multiple times.

Error log:

```
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\Devx8\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'build' ]
2 info using npm@6.9.0
3 info using node@v10.16.0
4 verbose stack Error: Invalid name: "Line up the heroes"
4 verbose stack     at ensureValidName (C:\Users\Devx8\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\normalize-package-data\lib\fixer.js:336:15)
4 verbose stack     at Object.fixNameField (C:\Users\Devx8\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\normalize-package-data\lib\fixer.js:215:5)
4 verbose stack     at C:\Users\Devx8\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\normalize-package-data\lib\normalize.js:32:38
4 verbose stack     at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
4 verbose stack     at normalize (C:\Users\Devx8\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\normalize-package-data\lib\normalize.js:31:15)
4 verbose stack     at final (C:\Users\Devx8\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:411:5)
4 verbose stack     at then (C:\Users\Devx8\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:160:5)
4 verbose stack     at C:\Users\Devx8\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:280:12
4 verbose stack     at C:\Users\Devx8\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:90:16
4 verbose stack     at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (internal/fs/read_file_context.js:53:3)
5 verbose cwd C:\xampp2\htdocs\todonew
6 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17134
7 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Devx8\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "build"
8 verbose node v10.16.0
9 verbose npm  v6.9.0
10 error Invalid name: "Line up the heroes"
11 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the npm package name must not contain space or capital letters change the `name` in your `package.json` file to something like `lineuptheheroes` (just for test) and try again, also check the documentation [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/package-name-guidelines) for how to write a valid name.